# RunningDifference(x) for multiple x values

Tags: yandex, clickhouse

My Table tbl_data(event_time, monitor_id,type,event_date,status)

```
select status,sum(runningDifference(event_time)) as delta from (SELECT status,event_date,event_time FROM tbl_data WHERE event_date >= '2018-05-01' AND monitor_id =3 ORDER BY event_time ASC) group by status
```

Result will be

```
status           delta
1               4665465
2                965
```

This query result give me right answer for single monitor_id, Now I required  it for multiple monitor_id,

How can I achieve it in single/same query??

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is achieved with conditional expressions. Like `SELECT ...,if(monitor_id = 1, status, NULL) AS status1,...` and then you do your aggregate function that, as you might know, skips NULL values. But I did some testing and it turns out that because of clickhouse internals `runningDifference()` can't distinguish columns originated from the same source. At the same time it distinguishes columns that came from different sources just fine. It is a bug.

I opened an issue on Github: https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/issues/2590

**UPDATE:** Devs reacted incredibly fast and with the latest source from `master` you can get what you want with the strategy I described. See the issue for code example.

Comment: I updated the answer. This bug is fixed in the latest source.